# Docker 1.12 Swarm: TLS changes

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers

On two hosts I installed on the first a docker swarm manager with the command `docker swarm init -advertise-addr=...`
and on the second a docker swarm node with `docker swarm join ...`
Now I changed the var `DOCKER_HOST=<docker-swarm-manager>:<port>`to the docker swarm manager with the right TCP-port.
Then I wanted to `ps` as a test of functionallity but I got the Message `Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?`.
I understand this message but my ask refers to the changes to the TLS-configuration. Are there any changes to the TLS-config with the new update to 1.12? Can I already use this documentation: [Configure Docker Swarm with TLS](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/configure-tls/) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't access the integrated swarm (started with `docker swarm`) by directly connecting to the swarm port like you do with the standalone containerized swarm. If you need remote access, you can configure the docker daemon (`dockerd`) to listen to a network interface from the daemon startup scripts. You should also secure that port with TLS if it can be reached by anyone you wouldn't trust with full root access on your server.

For a basic swarm test, you can access the swarm services locally from any manager with the `docker service ...` command, e.g. `docker service ls` and `docker service ps $servicename`.